# getting error when trying to createAccount in react native pjsip module

Tags: react-native, pjsip

I am trying to use https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip library in my react native project
but I am getting the following response

Below is the console of my code

> ```
> accounts undefined
> calls undefined
> settings undefined
> connectivity undefined
>
> Endpoint {
>   "_events": Object {},
>   "_maxListeners": undefined,
> }
>
> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.PjSipModule.createAccount')]
> ```

Appreciate the help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - TypeError: null is not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426691/react-native-typeerror-null-is-not-an-object)